# Movie where world leaders are tricked into destroying their nuclear arsenals

Tags: story-identification, movie

Recently my friend told me about a movie's plot whose name he didn't remember. It goes as such:

> The heads of all nations are assembled in a meet. They are planning to end the nuclear era for good. They have brought with them the remotes to all nuclear missiles in their respective countries. The American head asks them to fire their missiles into the air. But, they are all suspicious that the American head himself will receive them.
>
> So to assure them he takes initiative and destroys all the nuclear missiles of his country. Seeing this, the other heads also follow. After everyone has destroyed their missiles, the American head reveals another larger remote with a new, previously-hidden fleet of missiles. To scare everyone, he fires two missiles on two cities (I guess they were London and New York). Then he tells everyone about his plans to enslave every country on the globe.

Does anyone have any idea which movie this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**G.I.Joe: Retaliation**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1583421/) (2013)

> Zartan invites the world leaders to a summit at historic Fort Sumter, where he blackmails them into disabling their nuclear arsenals, and reveals that he has created Project Zeus: seven orbital kinetic bombardment weapons of mass destruction at his command.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I._Joe:_Retaliation)</sup>